# Proving NP completeness of optimal path cover

Tags: algorithm, np, np-complete, np-hard

This [paper](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/koods/papers/srikant93optimal.pdf) solves the optimal path cover problem for block graphs or bipartite permutation graph. In the third line of its introduction it's written that optimal path cover problem is NP-Complete and has given reference to "Computer and intractability: a guide to the theory of NP-completeness by David S. Johnson, Michael R. Garey". But I couldn't find its proof in the book. If anyone knows how to prove NP-Completeness of this problem then share your solution.

> **Optimal path cover problem:**
>   Given a graph G, find a minimum number of
>   vertex disjoint paths which together cover all the vertices of the
>   graph.

Comment: @D.W. This question is completely different from the others. What are you doing?

Comment: You are right, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the obvious decision variant (ie given k, is there a cover with k paths)

OPC(k=1) detects Hamiltonian paths, so clearly it's NP-hard.

It's also in NP because given the paths, checking whether they're disjoint and covering is easy.